# Rename XMLnode in Mule flow

Tags: xml, mule, dom4j

I have a Mule flow with a XML payload like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root type="1" name="blah">
  <blablah value="10" desc="Material" />
</root>
```

I want to rename the "root" node and tried using the xml-to-dom-transformer and expression component. However, I have no idea how to do that.I tried something like this that did not help:

```
    <expression-component><![CDATA[
      node = message.payload.getRootElement();
      node.renameNode = 'peo';
    ]]></expression-component>
```

Regards

Comment: How would you do the same in java  or any other programming tool  ?

Comment: I would do it codewise using LINQ2XML in C# or a simple Python oneliner.  Will not help me in a Mule flow though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I am suggesting the same approach as Anirban. But, a simpler XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <newRoot>
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="root/@type" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="root/@name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="root/node()" />
    </newRoot>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XSLT transformer in Mule to modify your XML
ref:- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xslt-transformer
It will be easy to modify any elements/nodes, values, attribute of an XML to a your own custom format in Mule community edition.
for example below xslt script will allow you to modify the **root** element name :-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <peo>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="root/@type" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="root/@name" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <blablah>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="root/blablah/@value" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="desc">
                    <xsl:value-of select="root/blablah/@desc" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </rootmodified>
        </peo>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here root element `<root>` is changed to `<peo>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dataweave (Transform Message).

Try:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml encoding="UTF-8"
---
{
    brandNewRoot @(type: payload.root.@type, name: payload.root.@name): {
        (payload)
    }
}
```

You will get this response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<brandNewRoot type="1" name="blah">
  <blablah desc="Material" value="10"></blablah>
</brandNewRoot>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an Enterprise Mule unfortunately, if I'm not mistaken Dataweave is not available in Community runtime?